# Method "POST" not allowed

Tags: python, django, post, django-rest-framework

I'm developing REST API with Django REST framework.

I defined custom detailed route like:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function, unicode_literals

class PermissionsMixin(object):
    @detail_route(methods=[u'get', u'post'], url_path='permissions')
    def detail_permissions(self, request, pk=None):
        ...
```

I've also tried `['get', 'post']`, but result is the same.

And test:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function, unicode_literals

class ProjectAPITestCase(APITestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        super(ProjectAPITestCase, self).setUp()

        self.factory = APIRequestFactory()

        self.detail_view = self.viewset.as_view({
            'get': 'retrieve',
            'put': 'update',
            'patch': 'partial_update',
            'delete': 'destroy',
        })

        self.resource_name = 'project'
        self.detail_permissions = lambda pk: reverse('api:{}-permissions'.format(self.resource_name),
                                                     kwargs={'pk': pk})


    def _detail_permissions(self, pk, data={}, user=None):
        request = self.factory.post(self.detail_permissions(pk), data=data, format='json')
        if user:
            force_authenticate(request, user)
        resp = self.detail_view(request, pk=pk)
        print(resp.data)
        resp.render()
        return resp

    def test_permissions(self):
        resp = self._detail_permissions(1, {}, self.user1)
        ...
```

When I run tests, `print` before rendering response returns:

```
{u'detail': u'Method "POST" not allowed.'}
```

I traced problem to [this line](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/views.py#L466), where `request.method.lower()` is `post` and `self.http_method_names` is `[u'get', u'post', u'put', u'patch', u'delete', u'head', u'options', u'trace']`.

I'm running app using `Python 2.7.9`

What am I doing wrong? How can I fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this code(add post method to the code like)

```
self.detail_view = self.viewset.as_view({
        'get': 'retrieve',
        'put': 'update',
        'patch': 'partial_update',
        'delete': 'destroy',
        'post': 'create'
    })
```

Comment: Thanks! This soled my problem. The right thing to add was ```'post': 'detail_permissions'```. Is there the way to link more functions to post request (depending on url)?